# upgradation in angular 17 causes translate pipe

Tags: pipe, ngx-translate, angular17

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqb41.png)`I have upgraded my project to angular 17 and getting error for pipe.  No pipe found with name 'translate'. have below code in app module with required imports.  And imported Translate Service in required component.

Upgradation causes lots of error. Is there any version compatibility issue ?`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess...

ngx-translate doess not official support NG-17:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

But have look at the filed issues: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1460

I think you need to import the TranslateModule (or just the Pipe) in all Modules /Standalone-Components to get it to work.

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TranslateModule], // just example
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyExampleComponent implements OnChanges {
```

If all of this does not help i would recommend to create a fresh empty new angular 17 project and try to get ngx-translate to work like you did in your project... and hopefully the issue will get clearer.